# LayerDrawable goes off the screen in a ListView and doesn't draw when I scroll ListView back to it

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, layerdrawable

I've a ListView and when my audio is paused I draw a LayerDrawable to show progress of how much was played. The problem is when I sroll this ListView element off the screen and get it back - I don't see any of the Image back there.

This is part from the adapter :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
       allView=convertView;
            if (view == null) { 
     view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);               
              }
............
  switch (whatToDo) {
      //here's my normal state of the Image
      case 0 :

          ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.imagestatus);
          break;
//here's my Paused state of the Image - what I need to stay on the screen
      case 1: 
    Log.e ("MyLog","paused! imagestatus="+p.imagestatus);
            //Drawing progress
          LayerDrawable ld= (LayerDrawable) ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.onpause);
            ClipDrawable cd=(ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.clip_pause);
            p.imagestatus=-p.imagestatus;

            cd.setLevel(4500+(30*p.imagestatus));
            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageDrawable(ld);

        break;
...
        return view;
      }
```

so, as you see, pretty much , usual getView method.
But when this Image goes off the screen - it never come back.
How can I fix it?

Comment: why do you negate   p.imagestatus ?

Comment: because if it's >0 - it's an R.id int, if it's less  - i negate it and use as a percentage for a LayerDrawable. But that's not the point

Comment: did you Log.d 4500+(30*p.imagestatus)? it should be between 0 and 10000, if p.imagestatus is an id then its a bit strange that you use it to set level

Comment: ok if you are sure the level is correct then set the level for outer LayerDrawable, not for inner ClipDrawable

Comment: yes, it shows correctly, but when I scroll listView off the screen - image disappears

Comment: did you call setLevel on LayerDrawable ?

Comment: of course, it's in the code above cd.setLevel(4500+(30*p.imagestatus));

Comment: man, do you read my comments at all?